# Generator function with yield Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, generator

I want to run a function in chunks so it will wait for 10k promises to resolve and then continue, I use the following generator function:

```
  function* processNodes(nodes, task){
    let i;
    let cnt = 0;
    let promiseArray = new Array(10000);
    let pInd = 0;
    let currId;

    for(i = 0; i<nodes.length; i++){
      currId = nodes[i];
      promiseArray[pInd++] = asyncFunc(currId, 0, task); // return a promise
      cnt++;

      if(cnt > 10000){
        console.log("going to yield", promiseArray)
        let pall = Promise.all(promiseArray);
        console.log("promise all", pall);
        yield pall;
        console.log("return from yield");  // never get here
        pInd = cnt = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

But it never returns from the yield even though I see that `pall` is resolved.

Is it possible to do something like this with generator functions?

Edit:
I think what I'm trying to do is to implement something like Bluebird's coroutine: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

Edit2: this is how I call this function:

```
let x = processNodes(allNodes, someSimpleTask);
x.next();
```

Comment: Can you show the code with which you test this function? `yield` will halt the function until the caller consumes the value.

Comment: This: `console.log("return from yield");  // never get here` @trincot

Comment: I did not mean that code, but the main code that calls the function.

Comment: It's too big to include here... @trincot

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your use-case: First, you create 10'000 promises. Then you `yield`, first for 10'000 promises, then 10'001, 10'002 and so on…

Comment: @nils I want to yield every 10k promises after 10k promises were made, not every 1. I reset the counter in the if.

Comment: You don't have to include the whole code, just create a few lines that calls this function and demonstrates the issue. I am quite sure the problem is not in the function, but in the way you use it.

Comment: I added how I call it, I can't include how the nodes were made, it's too big and complex and it's not even my code. @trincot

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. It would be great if you could include a running example though (with `asyncFunc`, `allNodes`,` someSimpleTask` etc.), just so we don't have to make guesses.

Comment: I can't, it's too big, but `asyncFunction` return a promise, you can assume it does something that takes time, like a network request or a large search. @nils

Comment: Just create a minimum viable example so we can test it without making any wrong assumptions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Code that has been provided is OK. I am moving on.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sk1kwLys/4/

Comment: Yes which is basically the same as my code, but mine doesn't return after the yield. @Icepickle

Comment: But it is not returning simply because you don't call it again, as you see from my code, it recalls next as long as there are more values to be considered. In your example you call next once, only the second call to next will resume the statement

Comment: You got it, you can write that as the answer and I'll accept. @Icepickle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't use the generator function as it should be. You are never getting to the `console.log('return from field')` because at the `yield`, the code stops executing after the yield statement. Only when you call the iterator again, it will continue after the yield statement (until the next yield statement)

So the generator creates an iterator, that has a `value` and a bool flag `done`. As long as the done is not set to true, you can/should call the next function again

A simplified version of your code can be the following

```js
// a very basic async function, just outputting the argument each 5 ms
function asyncFunc(arg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(arg);
      resolve();
    }, 5);
  });
}

// the generator
function* generator(processNodes, task) {
  var limit = 4,
    queue = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < processNodes.length; i++) {
    queue.push(task(processNodes[i]));
    if (queue.length >= limit) {
      yield Promise.all(queue);
      // clears the queue after pushing
      console.log('after queue');
      queue = [];
    }
  }
  // make sure the receiver gets the full queue :)
  if (queue.length !== 0) {
    yield Promise.all(queue);
  }
}

function runThroughArguments(args, task) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var nodes = generator(args, task),
        iterator = nodes.next();

      if (!iterator.done) {
        // if it's not done, we have to recall the functionallity
        iterator.value.then(function q() {
          setTimeout(() => {
            iterator = nodes.next();
            if (!iterator.done && iterator.value) {
              // call the named function (in this case called q) which is this function after the promise.all([]) completed
              iterator.value.then(q);
            } else {
              // everything finished and all promises are through
              resolve();
            }
          }, 2);
        });
      } else {
        iterator.value.then(resolve);
      }
    }, 2);
  });
}

runThroughArguments(
  ['hey', 'you', 'the', 'rock', 'steady', 'crew'], 
  asyncFunc).then(() => console.log('completed'));

console.log('runs before everything');
```

In the above snippet, it runs through a promise as well. So than you can be notified when the full queue is through, it is a bit more complex than the original snippet which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sk1kwLys/4/)

A more comprehensible explanation of the patterns you are using can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)